# Building dynamic URLs with a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have an Advert model. Each Advert belongs to an Area.

In an attempt to use more readable URLs, I've defined a custom path in my routes.rb:

```
match "/adverts/:area_id/:id" => "adverts#show", :as => :advert_semantic
```

This would produce something like

```
/adverts/manhattan/123
```

However, in very rare circumstances, it's possible that an advert is not assigned to an area. In those scenarios Rails throws an error and the page which calls for the path is not rendered.

I'd like to work around this by checking if the advert has an area assigned first, and in case there is no area, produce the regular path (/adverts/123) as a fallback.

What would you suggest is the best way to do this? E.g. would it be best to build a helper method which would do the above, or would this have an impact on performance if the method is called multiple times on the same page?

Comment: Would it be less code -and more easily maintaned- to add a "fake" area (maybe named "none"), and assign those rare adverts to it, so that as far as 99.9% of the code was concerned every advert was always assigned to some area?

Comment: Good point, thank you! Ended up implementing the fallback area as you suggested, works perfectly well. I'll still mark Peter's answer as correct as it may help others with a similar problem where implementing a fallback is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any extra actions taken impact performance of course, but if you use caution this shouldn't be prohibitive (and caching is always an option.)

A helper would be my choice in this case. Something like this..

```
def advert_link( advert )
  if advert.area.blank?
    link_to advert.title, advert
  else
    link_to advert.title, advert_semantic_path( advert, area_id: advert.area.id )
  end 
end
```

Would keep overhead pretty minimal, although it depends on how heavily it's used of course.